# Typescript : error TS2322: Type 'Object[]' is not assignable to type '[any]'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular6

I have this two interfaces in angular :

```
interface DropDown {
    items: DropDownItem[];
    buttonColor: string;
}
```

and

```
interface DropDownItem {
    name: string;
}
```

and I initialize a property in a component like this:

```
export class FiltersComponent implements OnInit {

firstDropDown: DropDown;


constructor() {
}

ngOnInit() {

    this.firstDropDown = {
        items: [
            {name: "all"},
            {name: 'first'}
        ],
        buttonColor: 'text-danger'
    };
}
```

}

Doing this I get this error:

> ERROR in src/app/shared/dropdown/dropdown.component.ts(22,13): error TS2322: Type 'DropDownItem[]' is not assignable to type '[any]'.
>     Property '0' is missing in type 'DropDownItem[]'.

What is the problem?? I would really appreciate some insight. Thanks!

**so the problem was in the dropdown.component.ts**

```
export class DropdownComponent implements OnInit {

show = false;
@Input() dropDown: DropDown;
selectedItem: any;
items: DropDownItem[]; //here i had [any]
buttonColor: string;

constructor() {
}
```

}

Comment: So the items object you created, is a list of any, but items needs to be a list of DropDownItem.  You need to define items correctly.

Comment: The code you posted works fine in the [playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/)...

Comment: how should i define them according to the interfaces that i have declared?

Comment: @Aaron i knoww right?? but it shows that error

Comment: please add `dropdown.component.ts` code

Comment: The error must come from somewhere else. `[any]` is a tuple type, but `DropDownItem[]` is an array type, so cannot be assigned to a tuple... but the code you've posted doesn't do this anywhere.

Comment: @DanielC.maan now i noticed it , i have been pulling my hair over this for about an hour, i had declared a property there of type [any]

Comment: @Aaron @ DanielC thanks guys i resolved it, sorry for troubling you

Comment: @RedionMuraj welcome